# How to improve dataset loop performance in mvc asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using following dataset looping for displaying the data on Razor view page. At this moment, I have my query returning only 100 records but when I call the function to display on the view page from controller, it is taking almost 6-7 seconds.

How can I improve the performance?

Thanks in advance

```
private void testreport(Modeltest model)
{
    try
    {           
        System.Data.DataSet ds = null;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.cls))
        {
            ds = getRepository.gerreports(model.ddl_1, model.ddl_2, null, null, null); 
        }
        else if (model.cls_idx=="0")
        {
            ds = getRepository.gerreports(model.ddl_1, model.ddl_2, model.ddl_3, null, null);
        }
        else
        {
            ds = getRepository.gerreports(model.ddl_1, model.ddl_2, model.ddl_3, model.cls, null);
        }

        StringBuilder tbl_h = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder tbl_m = new StringBuilder();              
        StringBuilder tbl_e = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder tbl_a = new StringBuilder();  

        var data = ds.Tables[0];
        foreach (System.Data.DataRow rw in data.Rows)
        {
            var r1 = rw["cls_T"].ToString();  
            var r3 = rw["cls_T_3"].ToString();
            var r15 = rw["cls_set"].ToString();
            var r17 = rw["cls_name"].ToString();
            var r18 = rw["cls_p_name"];
            var r19 = rw["cls_lbl"];
            var r20 = rw["cls_Type"].ToString();
            var r22 = rw["cls_Text"];
            var r23 = rw["cls_qt"].ToString();
            var r23_int = Convert.ToInt32(rw["cls_qt"].ToString());
            var r24 = rw["cls_resps"].ToString();                           

            if (r3 == "sc")
            {
                tbl_h.AppendFormat(@"<table class='table'><thead><tr><th>{0}</th><th>Reports</th><th>Class</th></tr></thead><tbody>", r19);
            }
            else if (r3 == "cmt")
            {
                tbl_h.AppendFormat(@"<table class='table1'><thead><tr><th>{0}</th><th>Reports</th></tr></thead><tbody>", r19);
            }

            if (r20 == "cls_qt" && (r15 == "q_ask" || r15 == "rpt"))
            {
                if (r24 > 0)
                {
                    if (r23_int >= 75)
                    {                       
                        tbl_m.AppendFormat(@"<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td></tr>", r22, r24, r23);
                    }
                    else if (r23_int >= 60 && r23_int < 75 )
                    {                       
                        tbl_m.AppendFormat(@"<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td></tr>", r22, r24, r23);
                    }
                    else if (r23_int > 0 && r23_int < 50)
                    {
                        tbl_m.AppendFormat(@"<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td></tr>", r22, r24, r23);
                    }
                }                       
                else
                {
                    tbl_m.AppendFormat(@"<tr><td>{0}</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>", r22);
                }
            }
            else if (r20 == "bk" && r17 == "cmt_cat")
            {
                if (r24 > 0 && r24 >= 100)
                {
                    tbl_m.AppendFormat(@"<tr><td><a href='{0}'>{0}</a></td><td>{1}</td></tr>", r18, r24);
                }
                else if (r24 > 0 && r24 < 100)
                {
                    tbl_m.AppendFormat(@"<tr><td><a href='{0}'>{0}</a></td><td>{1}</td></tr>", r18, r24);
                }
                else
                {
                    tbl_m.AppendFormat(@"<tr><td>{0}</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>", r18);
                }
            }

            if (r1 == "bfk")
            {
                tbl_e.AppendFormat(@"</tbody></table>");
            }               

            tbl_a.AppendFormat(tbl_h.ToString() + tbl_m.ToString() + tbl_e.ToString());
            tbl_h.Clear();
            tbl_m.Clear();
            tbl_e.Clear();
        }
        ViewBag.mreport = tbl_a.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("report: ", ex);
    }
}
```

My sql execute function -

```
private DataSet ExeSet()
{
    string sql = "select * from reportTest('test2017', 'Jan 2017', null, null, null) order by ID"
    try
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetCon()))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a profiler and see what is taking most of the time. My gut tells me that this line takes a hit when you loop through the first element: `foreach (System.Data.DataRow rw in data.Rows)`

Comment: @QualityCatalyst, I think you are right, but how I can improve that, just I changed the following - `DataTableReader dr = ds.CreateDataReader(); //foreach(System.Data.DataRow dr in data.Rows)
while(dr.Read())` but no luck

Comment: @QualityCatalyst, how I can improve that

Comment: When you hit `data.Rows` or `dr.Read()` the SQL gets executed. That may cost a lot if the query is expensive. `getRepository.gerreports(...)` is possibly a killer statement. I would take the generated SQL and test it separately such as with a SQL profiler in SQL Management Studio or similar, analyse the SQL, avoid full table scans (such as by adding correct indexes) etc.  Your C# code isn't the best/fastest I can think of, but considering the 100 rows, which you said is what you get, that shouldn't take even 50 ms if you have an average computer.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst, I have run the query in sql management studio which I copied from sql profiler, it is taking only less then a second. So, I think query is fine, problem in the code I provided

Comment: Probably you can take a look at this question [StringBuilder.Append vs AppendFormat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710504/stringbuilder-append-vs-stringbuilder-appendformat)

Comment: @Steve, I will have a look, thanks

Comment: @Steve, just I have use Append and did not improve anything

Comment: By the way this is always true _if (r24 > 0 && r24 >= 100)_ (for any positive) and this is always false _else if (r23_int >= 600 && r23_int < 75 )_ And perhaps you don't need at all the internal stringbuilders (h,m,e) if you reset them at each loop.

Comment: @Steve, thanks, I will do this

Comment: @Steve, I just edited my code, it is 60 not 600, I have tried what you said, but no improvement

Comment: I can only suggest you to measure your code to identify the point where you have problems. There is the Stopwatch class for this. You start it before an op, stop it after the op and then write somewhere the elapsedmilliseconds required for the operation. Start it again for the next op.

Comment: This loop isn't the problem. Profile and maybe post what happens inside `getRepository.gerreports()`

Comment: @HenkHolterman, Please see the updated code

Comment: @ArifChowdhury: Again, use a profiler while debugging through your code. Chances are high it'll take a while when calling `data.Rows`. It'll tell you the problem and again, I believe it is your SQL. Add a `break' after `tbl_e.Clear();` so you exit the loop after the first row and I guess it'll be nearly the same poor performance. Your SQL must be bad looking at the code. As I and Henk said before: look into your reports. They are likely to be slow as dogs. Try to understand how accessing DBs work and WHEN your SQL is executed.

Answer (score 0):

In general, your performance problem is probably `DataSet` itself. DataSet is meant for being able to keep consistent *disconnected* copies of data (e.g., for occasionally-connected apps). Unless you have a need to keep a disconnected copy of your data or need to load a version of the data that you saved somewhere other than the database, you will see much better performance using an implementation of `IDataReader` instead (e.g., `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader`).

Comment: Thanks Dusty, I will try to use IDataReader

Comment: Data sets use data readers internally so they must be faster. In this particular case it is likely that changing to data readers will improve the time only marginally. Problem unsolved. It's only a hundred items, not 100,000. Look at the code closely: it is (kind of) okay and should execute fast. Only problem appears to be the SQL that is been executed. Possibly loads of full table scans included when getting the reports.